# Chrome getfileattachment download failed due to missing sd card

Tags: chrome-for-android

I am running Android 7.0 on a Huawei P8 lite 2017 (brand new)
Every time I try to download a file from Google Chrome I get the error message:
"getfileattachment download failed due to missing sd card".

What I know right now:
1) The SD card works (Pictures from the camera are saved there)
2) I tried the workarounds consisting in force stopping chrome, denying and reenabling permission, and clearing cache as shown on several youtube videos such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__pEL3k8wQQ) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZ3yRrL5JUI)
3) Gmail can download attachments (it stores them on the internal memory, though).
4) When I first inserted my SD card, I received a warning that the card is old and this might result in suboptimal performances.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Follow from chrome are by default downloaded to your internal memory, and i don't think there is a way to change that. Did you by any chance try forcing it to download to sd and what were the methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing data of the chrome app

Go into your phone settings>application manager (or apps)>chrome>storage>manage space>clear data

Have in mind that clearing data in chrome will delete all your history in the app, unless you were signed into your Google account, in that case it will all come back as soon as you sign back in

Answer (score 1):

Try ERASING (reformatting) the SD Card while inserted in the phone.

1. Back up your data
2. Go to device “Settings”, then select “Storage”.
3. Select your "SD Card", then tap the “three-dot menu“ (top-right), now select “Settings” from in there.
4. Now select “Format as internal”, and then “Erase & Format”.
5. Your SD Card will now be formatted as internal storage.
6. Reboot your phone.

Reference:
http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-3325411/download-due-card-missing.html

Comment: It's worth letting the OP know that this method will totally wipe their sd card.

Comment: Yes, it is a rather "extreme" method! I will try it as soon as I am convinced that there are no other workarounds.